# Akka + Camel + Context-Provider

Tags: apache-camel, akka, netty

Dear Camel/Akka/Netty Masters!

I've created UntypedConsumerActor which consumes tcp connection:

```
public class TcpEndpoint extends UntypedConsumerActor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpEndpoint.class);

    public static Props props = Props.create(TcpEndpoint.class);

    @Override
    public String getEndpointUri() {
        return "netty4:tcp://localhost:8000?decoders=#fdDecoder,#fdHandler";
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Throwable {
        log.error("onReceived");
    }

}
```

In case to configure decoders for netty component, I've created ContextProvider:

```
public class FDCamelContext implements ContextProvider {

    public DefaultCamelContext getContext(ExtendedActorSystem system) {
        JndiRegistry registry = new JndiRegistry();
        registry.bind("fdDecoder", new FDDecoder());
        registry.bind("fdHandler", new FDHandler());

        DefaultCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
        return context;
    }
}
```

Now, when I send message there is no call on onReceive method. Why? When I set DefaultContextProvider and configure netty to consumes textlines everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found problem. Maybe it helps someone:

It is necesarry to fire channelRead event:

```
ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
```